# how to get all documents from Firestore and make a loop (Cloud Functions)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access data in my Firestore database using cloud function using Javascript
I need to loop on all the documents I have (I have 7 documents), but it only returns the first document and prints it in the logs, and I don't know why.
this is my code

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs", {structuredData: true});
  

  //loop on the document
  const facultyRef = await admin.firestore().collection('faculty').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        response.send("Hello Firebase");
        //print the doc id in the logs
        functions.logger.info(doc.id);
    });
});

});
```

Note: It print 'Hello Firebase' in the page, and print 'hello logs' and only the first document Id in the logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `response.send()` you are actually terminating your Cloud Function, see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).

If you want to log all the doc IDs, do as follows:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs", { structuredData: true });

    const facultyQuerySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('faculty').get();

    facultyQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        //print the doc id in the logs
        functions.logger.info(doc.id);
    });

    // We terminate the Function AFTER the loop has completed
    response.send("Hello Firebase");

});
```